# MySQL licencing for commercial use

Tags: mysql, licensing

Can someone explain to me the following:

We are running a website with a web service using MySQL and we are getting paid for it monthly. Can we use MySQL community edition for this? Can we use MySQL community edition for development of this kind of software? We are not distributing our source code anywhere.

Another example: Can you write a website using CMS using MySQL for a customer? Can you use the free edition?

Comment: MySQL is open source under GPL license, so yes, you can use anywhere you want.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [licensing/legal advice](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1699210)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it *should* be fine, as it is under the GPL license.